# Problems converting string to integer splitting two variables in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.4

Using Python 3.4 in Idle. Why am I getting this error message...

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '4 4'
```

when converting my input statement into an integer. I'm trying to put `int` in my input statement vs using

```
num1 = int(num1) 
num2 = int(num2)
```

The first way works, but why doesn't the second way? The second way would work if I ran this code:

```
number = int(input("Number?"))
print(number)
```

So why doesn't it work the second way?

**First way works:**

```
#Ask the user to input 2 values and store them in variables num1 num2

num1, num2 = input("Enter 2 numbers: ").split()

#Convert the strings into regular numbers Integer
num1 = int(num1)
num2 = int(num2)

# Type problems and store in a variable
sum = num1 + num2
difference = num1 - num2
product = num1 * num2
quotient = num1 / num2
remainder = num1 % num2

print("{} + {} = {}".format(num1,num2,sum))
print("{} - {} = {}".format(num1,num2,difference))
print("{} * {} = {}".format(num1,num2,product))
print("{} / {} = {}".format(num1,num2,quotient))
print("{} % {} = {}".format(num1,num2,remainder))
```

This way doesn't work. I only put this piece of the code to show what I did differently. Besides this line and the other way to convert the string into an integer (num = int) the rest of the code is the same.

**2nd way**:

```
num1, num2 = int(input("Enter 2 numbers: ")).split()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second way is trying to convert `4 4` into an `int` which it can't do, you need to apply `int` to each individual number as a string, so your code becomes:

```
num1, num2 = map(int, input('Enter 2 numbers: ').split())
```

On a side note - by calling your variable `sum` later on you're shadowing the builtin `sum` which may lead to problems further down the line - I normally use `total`.

You can also make use of the functions in the `operator` module to make it a bit simpler:

```
import operator as op

num1, num2 = map(int, input('Enter 2 numbers: ').split())
for symbol, func in (
    ('+', op.add), ('-', op.sub), ('*', op.mul),
    ('/', op.truediv), ('%', op.mod)
):
    print('{} {} {} = {}'.format(num1, symbol, num2, func(num1, num2)))
    # or print(num1, symbol, num2, '=', func(num1, num2))
```

Entering `4 4` will give you:

```
4 + 4 = 8
4 - 4 = 0
4 * 4 = 16
4 / 4 = 1.0
4 % 4 = 0
```